# Why does the second requirement of a Basis for a Topology make sense?

Tags: general-topology

Why does the second requirement of a basis, i.e. that a point in two sets must also be contained in a third set contained in the intersection of the two set, make sense? Why is that what we should think of as a basis?

Comment: If you have a basis, arbitrary union of elements in the basis are suppose to form a topology. This condition is used to show the collection of arbitrary unions is a topology.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how that is implied from the statement given?

Comment: In a topology the intersection of two open sets is suppose to be open. In the topology generate by a basis, the intersection of two basic open sets should be open, i.e. an union of some other basic open sets. You use the second condition to find a basic open containing each point in your intersection. Then you take union over all these to see that the intersection is a union of basic open sets.

Answer (score 1):

We want basic open sets to be open, so the intersection of $U,V$ in the base should be open, and so (if it is a base!) the union of basic elements itself. So for every point $x \in U \cap V$ we want that there is some basic set $W_x$ that contains $x$ and sits inside $U \cap V$ (and the union of all these $W_x$, for $x \in U \cap V$, then equals $U \cap V$).
So it's a necessary condition if we want basic sets to be open, and all open sets to be unions of basic sets.

Answer (score 0):

This property ensures that the intersection of two open sets is also an open set.

Recall that given a basis $\mathcal B$ for a topology, the topology generated by $\mathcal B$ consists of all sets of the form $\bigcup \mathcal A$, where $\mathcal A \subseteq \mathcal B$. Another way of saying this is that $U \subseteq X$ is open in the generated topology if and only if for each $x \in U$ there is a $V \in \mathcal B$ with $x \in V \subseteq U$.

Now to show that the intersection of two open sets is open, let $U_1 , U_2$ be open, and consider $x \in U_1 \cap U_2$. Since $U_1$ is open and $x \in U_1$ there is a $V_1 \in \mathcal B$ such that $x \in V_1 \subseteq U_1$. Similarly, there is a $V_2 \in \mathcal B$ such that $x \in V_2 \subseteq U_2$.

But how can we find a $W \in \mathcal B$ such that $x \in W \subseteq U_1 \cap U_2$? This is where that second property comes in. By that second property there is a $W \in \mathcal B$ such that $x \in W \subseteq V_1 \cap V_2$ and then we also have $x \in W \subseteq U_1 \cap U_2$.